# npm: Using angular 6: Build error ts2307 cannot find module "ngx-loading-mask"

Tags: angular, npm, build, npm-install

Okay, I've exhausted every Google search I can think of to resolve this issue.

I'm performing an upgrade from 5.x to 6.x and have hit a brick wall.
Running npm install works with no errors and there are 2 WARNS which are not an issue.

There are two odd issues I see.
1. When I run the command npm list packageName I can see most package versions but there are some that do not show anything. I see the package in the folder.

**Why would this happen?**

2. When I attempt to run the command ng build, I get the same 1 error message every single time and the package DOES exist in the folder.

> TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-loading-mask'

TS2307: Cannot find module 'package'
TS2307: Cannot find module 'packageName'

If you have ran into a similar issue (does not have to be the same package as me) where the package is clearly in the node_modules folder, how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out from another that this package was not updated for use with Angular 6 and to remove it completely from our project.